# How to cancel a Stream when using Stream.periodic?

Tags: dart

I'm having trouble canceling a stream that is created using the Stream.periodic constructor. Below is my attempt at canceling the stream. However, I'm having a hard time extracting out the 'count' variable from the internal scope. Therefore, I can't cancel the subscription.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  int count = 0;
  final Stream newsStream = new Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (_) {
    return _;
  });

  StreamSubscription mySubscribedStream = newsStream.map((e) {
    count = e;
    print(count);
    return 'stuff $e';
  }).listen((e) {
    print(e);
  });

  // count = 0 here because count is scoped inside mySubscribedStream
  // How do I extract out 'count', so I can cancel the stream?
  if (count > 5) {
    mySubscribedStream.cancel();
    mySubscribedStream = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: .. or is it zero because you're not checking it after updating it, but just after creating the stream?

Comment: In retrospect, I shouldn't have said `count` was scoped inside `mySubscribedStream`. If I print out `count` right before the if statement, it equals zero because it prints immediately when this code is run instead of waiting on the stream to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather use `take(5)` instead of checking `> 5` and then cancel

```
final Stream newsStream = new Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (_)  => count++);

newsStream.map((e) {
    count = e;
    print(count);
    return 'stuff $e';
  }).take(5).forEach((e) {
    print(e);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to know how to cancel a Stream.periodic.

Comment: Store the subscription returned by ’listen(...)` and call `cancel()` on it.

Comment: Wouldn't this simply cancel the subscription to the stream and not the actual stream? I have a stream.periodic that I'm using to poll an API regularly. I want to stop polling the api if it receives a certain response. If I cancel listeners, won't it still poll but just have no subscribers to notify?

Comment: A stream without subscribers does nothing. It has no active references pointing to it anymore and will be garbage collected.

Comment: Doesn't the garbage collection cause potential memory leaks since the stream is not `close()`d?

Comment: @SimonL periodic is usually supposed to keep running. If you want to use it for example in a Flutter widget only while it is shown, you can unsubscribe from it in `dispose()`. For this you need to use `var sub = newsstream.listen(...);` instead of `map(...)`, so that you then can call `sub.cancel();` The garbage collector would take care of it, but if the widget is not attached anymore and the stream still emits an event before the GC gets to it, the event handler code might cause errors when the code depends on the widget still being attached.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Helped a lot bro, thank you @GünterZöchbauer!

Comment: side stepping the problem doesn't really answer the question. Thats why the question got +10 and you +2

Comment: Just check the comments