# How to use dynamic interval time in Stream.periodic event in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder, periodic-task

I'm struggling to find out a way to emit stream periodically with dynamic interval time in Flutter. I'm not sure, is it really possible or not. One workaround may be canceling the old periodic stream and reinitialize it with a new time interval but my periodic stream with asyncMap doesn't have a cancel option. I could use stream.listen that has cancel method but I purposely need asyncMap to convert the Future event to stream. In this case, what I can do please suggest to me.

My code snippet -

```
int i = 0;

int getTimeDiffForPeriodicEvent() {
  i++;
  return (_timeDiffBetweenSensorCommands * commandList.length + 1) * i;
}

StreamBuilder(
      stream: Stream.periodic(
              Duration(seconds: maskBloc.getTimeDiffForPeriodicEvent()))
          .asyncMap((_) async => maskBloc.getDataFromMask()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container();
      },
    );
```

Comment: i dont get it: you want your stream to emit some data periodically or you want something else?

Comment: I want to emit a stream periodically but at different time intervals. I mean periodic time intervals should be dynamic.

Comment: Or is it possible to cancel Stream.periodic().asyncMap() ?

Comment: so everytime new value is emitted it happens at different intervals? for example first value after 1 sec, second value after 6 sec, third value after 3 sec? that is 1: 00:01, 2: 00:07, 3: 00:10 ?

Comment: That's right. with different time intervals.

Comment: the easiest solution is `async*` generator like: `Stream<int> randomPeriodicStream() async* {
int i = 0;

while (true) {
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000 + Random().nextInt(3000)));
print('yielding $i');
yield i++;
}
}`

Comment: or in your particular case: `randomPeriodicStream() async* { while (true) { await Future.delayed(getTimeDiffForPeriodicEvent()); yield await getDataFromMask(); } }` - thats all, no need for `Stream.periodic`,  `asyncMap` etc

Comment: what is randomPeriodicStream() function here? Can you please share the full code with StreamBuilder widget coupling?

Comment: This not working in my side - StreamBuilder(
      stream:randomPeriodicStream() async* { int i = 0;  while (true) { await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000 + Random().nextInt(3000))); print('yielding $i'); yield i++; } },
      builder: (context, snapshot) {return Container();});

Comment: `randomPeriodicStream` is an [async* generaor](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch) - it produces the `Stream` you can use directly in `StreamBuilder` - simply use `final randomStream = randomPeriodicStream();` and inside `StreamBuilder` add `stream: randomStream,`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Hi, need one more help regarding background fetching. I want to call this randomPeriodicStream function in the background, is it really possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible with `Stream.periodic`, but you could perhaps create a class that can start a stream and sleep based on some mutable variable by using `async*` and `yield`:

```
class AdjustablePeriodStream {
  Duration period;
  AdjustablePeriodStream(this.period);

  Stream<void> start() async* {
    while (true) {
      yield null;
      print('Waiting for $period');
      await Future.delayed(period);
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow changing the period fairly easily:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final ten = Duration(milliseconds: 10);
  final twenty = Duration(milliseconds: 20);
  final x = AdjustablePeriodStream(ten);

  x.start().take(5).listen((_) {
    print('event!');
    x.period = (x.period == ten ? twenty : ten);
  });
}
```

You can see the example output here:

https://dartpad.dev/6a9cb253fbf29d8adcf087c30347835c

```
event!
Waiting for 0:00:00.020000
event!
Waiting for 0:00:00.010000
event!
Waiting for 0:00:00.020000
event!
Waiting for 0:00:00.010000
event!
Waiting for 0:00:00.020000
```

It just swaps between waiting 10 and 20 milliseconds (presumably you have some other mechanism you want to use for this). You'd probably also want some way to cancel the stream (which would bail out of the `while (true)` loop) but I ommitted it here to keep the code short and specific.

Comment: Hello Danny, Thanks for your great comment. But I'm wondering if there is any way to cancel Stream.periodic that handles with asyncMap. You can see the comment section in this post where they talk about canceling the subscription returned by 'Stream.listen(...)'. But my question is, is it possible to cancel stream.periodic that deals with asyncMap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583042/how-to-cancel-a-stream-when-using-stream-periodic

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - if you're using asyncMap() I presume you're still calling .listen() on it somewhere? In which case you could cancel that StreamSubscription?

Comment: No, I'm using StreamBuilder which doing the listening things that you can see in my code snippet. StreamBuilder(
      stream: Stream.periodic(
              Duration(seconds:  5))
          .asyncMap((_) async => maskBloc.getDataFromMask()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container();
      },
    );

Comment: But I'm not sure how to cancel the timer of Stream.periodic event in this case.

Comment: Please see the commented part in this code snippet - final stream = Stream.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: maskBloc.getTimeDiffForPeriodicEvent()))
        .asyncMap((_) async => maskBloc.getDataFromMask());
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        stream.cancel();//My problem is : This method cancel is not defined for the type stream
        return Container();
      },
    );

Comment: You should be able to use something like the code I gave above. You could add a cancel() method that sets `period = null` then change the `where (true)` loop to by `while (period != null)`. Now, calling `cancel()` would cause the stream to end. Then you just need to keep a reference to the instance of `AdjustablePeriodStream` in your state, and use the stream returned by `start()` in your streambuilder (you can call asyncMap on it).

Comment: Hi, need one more help regarding background fetching. I want to call this AdjustablePeriodStream in the background, is it really possible?